# Не выводить строку, в которой определенный символ

Tags: php, веб-программирование

У меня импортирована база с описаниями товаров. И там где описания нету, в строке стоят кавычки ("). Я вывожу список товаров, и хочу сделать так, что если строка описания это кавычки то не выводить ее. Однако на деле не получается. Как это организовать? Пример кода ниже

```
if ($row['description'] <>'"')  echo "Описание: ".$row['description']."<br><br>\n";
```

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump` такого поля. Может там 2 апострофа?

Comment: ваше сообщение сподвигло на верную цель. Там были не просто кавычки, а пробел и кавычка. Спасибо!

Comment: Хочу отметить, что неплохо бы выяснить, почему у вас пустое описание обозначается столь экзотическим образом. Выяснить, и больше так не делать.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить не пуста ли строка достаточно :

```
if ($row['description'])  
  echo "Описание: ".$row['description']."<br><br>\n";
```

Либо чтобы удостовериться что у вас есть хотя бы одна буква или цифра в переменной, а не просто пустые строки и/или кавычки :

```
 $desc =  $row['description'];
 if (preg_match('/[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]]/', $desc) || preg_match('/[0-9]/', $desc))
 {
     //Содержит по меньшей мере одну букву или одну цифру
     echo "Описание: ".$row['description']."<br><br>\n";
 }
```

Comment: Тогда уже `if (empty($row['description']))`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, как это? Если пустое поле, то вывести пустое поле?

Comment: Ну `!empty(...)`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Результат тот же, но я предпочитаю более короткую запись. Без empty();

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а в чем смысл здесь писать empty?

Comment: @koks_rs мне вот интересно, неужели так сложно прочитать вопрос, на который отвечаешь?

Comment: Пройдёмся регулярками по кавычкам! Добавьте хоть русских букв..

Comment: @Ипатьев, и что там в вопросе? Прочитал, вроде.

Comment: @vp_arth, добавил. Чем плохи регулярки? Предложите более элегантный вариант?

Comment: `trim($desc)!='"'`, а лучше `UPDATE...SET desc=null..`

Comment: @vp_arth `trim($desc)!='"'` у автора же пробел между кавычками может быть. А насчет изменить пустые поля в БД так вопрос ясно стоит : "как не выводить строку..."

Comment: Между какими кавычками? Она там одна

Comment: @vp_arth, где одна кавычка там  ̶ ̶и̶ ̶д̶в̶е̶ ̶  вообще значит можно встретить что угодно.. может там точка с запятой в след стороке будет

Comment: гибкость мышления просто поразительная

Comment: Кстати, я бы объединил эти регулярки, и упростил бы за счёт флага `i`. И у вас там `]` лишняя